# ebay API: Get all seller items by seller ID in PHP returns 500 error

Tags: php, ebay-api

I am trying to build a method to pull all active auctions by a seller by ID.  It seems like it should be a simple thing to me.  Getting items by keyword is easy, and I am using the following:

```
public function findItems($keyword = '', $limit = 2){

$url    = $this->url . '?';
$url .= 'operation-name=findItemsByKeywords';
$url .= '&service-version=' . $this->version;
$url .= '&keywords=' . urlencode($keyword);
$url .= '&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=' . $limit;

$url .= '&security-appname='. $this->app_id;
$url .= '&response-data-format=' . $this->format;

return json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);

} // findItems()
```

This is part of a class building tutorial at:
http://wern-ancheta.com/blog/2013/04/03/getting-started-with-ebay-finding-api/

I've tried substituting the operation name with `GetSellerList` and using the `userID` to get a specific seller's goods list, but every combination I've tried using all of the required arguments comes back with a 500 error (from eBay's servers).

http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/GetSellerList.html

This seems like it should be a very basic and simple process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tutorial used in the blog post is for the [Finding](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/finding/Concepts/FindingAPIGuide.html) api.

The `GetSellerList` call is part of the [Trading](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/guides/ebayfeatures/index.html) api. The trading api is much more complicated to use as it requires an XML or SOAP request.

Once you get used to making SOAP requests it isn't that difficult to use. Here is an example of the my [eBay SOAP client](https://gist.github.com/jmsfwk/b1ac9aacd6a42696551d).